# How can I test a Lib in CakePHP2.4?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp-2.0

I moved some code from a model to a Lib in my app, because it can be used from 2 models and is not database related. It is an uploadhandler, which is used from my two models. It is placed at /app/Lib/UploadHandler.php
That works. Hurray...

But: How can I write Unit Tests for my Lib? It is a lib not 3rd party classes which would belong into the vendor folder. I created a TestClass in an new folder "Lib" in
/app/Test/Case/Lib/UploadHandlerTest.php

What I do so far is:

```
App::uses('UploadHandler', 'Lib');

/**
 * UploadHandler Test Case
 *
*/
class UploadHandlerTestCase extends CakeTestCase
{
    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fixtures = array();

    /**
     * setUp method
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->UploadHandler = ClassRegistry::init('UploadHandler');
    }

    /**
     * tearDown method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->UploadHandler);

        parent::tearDown();
    }




    public function testHandleFileUpload() {....
```

which gives me errors like:
MissingTableException
Table sang_upload_handlers for model UploadHandler was not found in datasource test.
Test case: UploadHandlerTestCase(testHandleFileUpload)

But - hey I don't need the database! All my methods run just with the data I give the public methods.

What would be the proper initialization of my test class?

Thank you for any help!

Calamity Jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anybody except me is interested in it I found a way to make it work like I want.

First the folder structure:

Class location:

app/Lib/MyLib.php

Test class location:

app/Test/Case/Lib/MyLibTest.php

By this you can see the Test for your library in the CakePHP  browser webinterface.

Second: How to prevent the error about dabase tables.
The answer is quite simple: Just let your testclass extend not the CakeTestCase, but use the original  PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and you will have no trouble with missing tables.

Duh....

Example:

```
require_once DS.'var'.DS.'www'.DS.'myproject'.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'/Lib/UploadHandler.php';

/**
 * UploadHandler Test Case
 *
*/
class UploadHandlerTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{....
```

I was happy to help myself ;) I guess a lot of sleep during the change of the year did the trick ;)

Calamity Jane